# Creating symbolic links using Visual Basic

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, winapi

What is the easiest way to create symbolic links using Visual Basic?  The following code is something simple that I wrote up using the Win32 API, but does not seem to be working:

```
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
Public Class SymbolicLinker
   Private Enum SymbolicLink
      File = 0
      Directory = 1
   End Enum

  <DllImport("kernel32.dll")> _
  Private Shared Function CreateSymbolicLink(lpSymlinkFileName As String, lpTargetFileName As String, dwFlags As SymbolicLink) As Boolean
  End Function
End Class
```

What is confusing me is that the following C# code works fine:

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace Testbed_SymbolicLinks
{
   class SymbolicLinker
   {
       [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
       static extern bool CreateSymbolicLink(string lpSymlinkFileName, string lpTargetFileName, SymbolicLink dwFlags);

       enum SymbolicLink
       {
           File = 0,
           Directory = 1
       }
}
```

}

Am I somehow porting the code incorrectly from C# to VB?

**EDIT:**
My use case is very simple:

```
Module Module1
    Sub Main()
        Console.WriteLine("Entering application.")
        Try
            CreateNewSymbolicLink()
        Catch e As Exception
            Console.WriteLine("An error occured.")
        End Try
        Console.ReadKey()
    End Sub
    Sub CreateNewSymbolicLink()
        Console.WriteLine("Enter the name of a valid file:  ")
        Dim file As String = Console.ReadLine()
        Console.WriteLine("Enter the name of a symbolic file:  ")
        Dim symbol As String = Console.ReadLine()
        Dim success As Boolean = SymbolicLinker.CreateSymbolicLink(symbol, file, SymbolicLink.File)
        If success Then
            Console.WriteLine("Web call was success")
        Else
            Console.WriteLine("Web call was a failure")
        End If
    End Sub
End Module
```

Comment: Don't forget that `CreateSymbolicLink` requires elevation on a normal system.

Comment: Please show an MCVE. We can't see how you call the function. "Not working" is of no use to us. You have to be precise and give details.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan In this case, I think it's pretty obvious that "not working" means a symbolic link is not being created when the function is called, but if you must, I have added my MCVE.

Comment: @JonathanPotter Jonathan, thank you for the response.  Sorry for the basic question, but can you explain what that means?  Thank you.

Comment: He means that you must run the application with Administrator privileges.

Comment: @NotCloseToFour `CreateSymbolicLink` requires the SE_CREATE_SYMBOLIC_LINK_NAME privilege which, with UAC enabled, you will only have when the process is elevated (e.g. right-click, Run as Administrator).

Comment: @Pierre-LucPineault Thank you!  Yes, I am running with admin rights in both cases above (the VB and the C#).  Only the C# case works as intended.

Comment: I don't think it's at all obvious. Stating such details and including an MCVE is very important. You don't call `Marshal.GetLastWin32Error` to obtain an error code. If you did it would shed light on your problem.

Comment: You should also show the real code. CreateSymbolicLink has three arguments.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan The real code is there above my edit, from my initial post.  The code you must be looking at is my function that calls into CreateSymbolicLink.  When I do call Marshal.GetLastWin32Error, I'm getting a return value of 0, so there are no failures that are happening.  I am simply getting false back from the function when I call it with two valid file location on my computer.  Admittedly, I am very inexperienced with VB so I am having trouble going on from here.  I'm unsure how to determine why it is returning false since I do know its inner workings.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: You are not showing your real code. `CreateSymbolicLink` has three arguments. You supply only two.

Comment: What does MCVL mean?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have not shown your real code, so it's impossible to say what went wrong. Here is code that does work:

```
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices

Public Class SymbolicLinker

    Public Enum SymbolicLink
        File = 0
        Directory = 1
    End Enum

    <DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError:=True)> _
    Public Shared Function CreateSymbolicLink(lpSymlinkFileName As String, _
                                              lpTargetFileName As String, _
                                              dwFlags As SymbolicLink) As Boolean
    End Function

End Class

Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        CreateNewSymbolicLink("C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\link.txt", _
                              "C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\foo.txt")
        Console.ReadKey()
    End Sub

    Sub CreateNewSymbolicLink(linkName As String, targetName As String)
        If Not SymbolicLinker.CreateSymbolicLink(linkName, targetName, _
                                                 SymbolicLinker.SymbolicLink.File) Then
            Console.WriteLine(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error())
        End If
    End Sub

End Module
```

Note that I added the `SetLastError` parameter to the `DllImport` attribute. This allows us to capture the error code in case of failure. I also demonstrated how to obtain that error code, and also when to do so. That is, if and only if, the function return value indicates failure.

Comment: This is a beautiful answer, but for some reason I can't get it to work.  CreateSymbolicLink is always returning 0.  I am running as administrator and MKLINK works fine.  GetLastWin32Error() is returning "The Operation Completed Successfully" (or something like that).  I know I'm giving you very little to go on, but I'm stuck.  I copied pasted your code exactly into Visual Studio and it fails.  Can you think of any other dependencies I might be missing?  Windows 10, no compression, no access denial problems.  Please don't stress for an answer; anything off the top of your head would help.

Comment: @SixSigmaGuy I don't know, it works fine here still

Comment: Thanks for checking. It must have something to do with my configuration settings. Your response helps me to move forward.